# smartdatadiscovery​/predictionDefinitions

Tags: rest, einstein, workbench

I am having issues in executing smartdatadiscovery​/predictionDefinitions API via workbench - I am gettging the below exception

Service not found at: /services/data/v50.0/smartdatadiscovery​/predictionDefinitions

HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found Date: Wed, 02 Dec 2020 13:06:14 GMT Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536002; includeSubDomains Public-Key-Pins-Report-Only: pin-sha256="9n0izTnSRF+W4W4JTq51avSXkWhQB8duS2bxVLfzXsY="; pin-sha256="5kJvNEMw0KjrCAu7eXY5HZdvyCS13BbA0VJG1RSP91w="; pin-sha256="njN4rRG+22dNXAi+yb8e3UMypgzPUPHlv4+foULwl1g="; max-age=86400; includeSubDomains; report-uri="https://a.forcesslreports.com/hpkp-report/00D4K000004jcwim"; Expect-CT: max-age=86400, report-uri="https://a.forcesslreports.com/Expect-CT-report/00D4K000004jcwim" X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block X-Robots-Tag: none X-B3-TraceId: 73041360ca86abf5 X-B3-SpanId: 73041360ca86abf5 X-B3-Sampled: 0 Cache-Control: no-cache,must-revalidate,max-age=0,no-store,private Set-Cookie: BrowserId=KCKP9jSfEeuYF48BYFlDfA; domain=.salesforce.com; path=/; expires=Thu, 02-Dec-2021 13:06:14 GMT; Max-Age=31536000 Sforce-Limit-Info: api-usage=65/185000 Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8 Transfer-Encoding: chunked
[ { "errorCode" : "NOT_FOUND", "message" : "The requested resource does not exist" } ]

I have Einstein Analytics Plus permission set assigned to my user alreadyUser-added image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you have copied the Resource URL from the salesforce [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=bi_edd_prediction_service_prediction_definition.htm&type=5)

If yes, I see there are special characters in the URL as a prefix and suffix for  /smartdatadiscovery​/ .

Verified on https://www.textmagic.com/free-tools/unicode-detector
[image: Special Character present]

When I copied the REST URL you posted, it failed with the same error message that you posted.

After removing special characters, I tried with below resource URL and was able to fetch the results

```
/services/data/v50.0/smartdatadiscovery/predictiondefinitions
```

[image: Success]

I have reached out to our team internally to have this corrected in the documentation and will update this thread as I have more information. Hope this helps!

-Regards,
Salesforce Support

Comment: Thansk a lot, yes it worked. I never thought that this could be the issue. Thanks again.