# Salesforce CMS REST API: /search `NOT_FOUND`

Tags: rest-api, connect-api, salesforce-cms

I am attempting to hit the `/connect/cms/delivery/channels/{{channelId}}/contents​/search?page=1&pageSize=20&queryTerm=test&scope=All` REST API endpoint but am getting the following 404 response errors.

> NOTE: `{{channelId}}` is a variable. It is replaced with the actual `channelId` when run.

```json
[
  {
    "errorCode": "NOT_FOUND",
    "message": "The requested resource does not exist"
  }
]
```

I've verified that the authentication is working as hitting the `/connect/cms/delivery/channels` endpoint works perfectly returning:

[image]

Hitting the `/connect/cms/delivery/channels/channelId​/contents/query` also works too. Its just the `/search` endpoint that returns an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I tried the URL you posted I too got 404 error code. Then I manually typed in the endpoint `/services/data/v50.0/connect/cms/delivery/channels/0ap7F000000KyutQAC/contents/search?page=1&pageSize=20&queryTerm=test&scope=All` and it succeeded(You too should get the success with this URL).

when I posted the endpoint in the [online special character identifier](https://www.textmagic.com/free-tools/unicode-detector) , I noticed a special character that is giving the 404 error.
[image]

Comment: the `{{channelId}}` is a postman variable, so it replaces it with the actual `channelId` when running the endpoint. Is there a reason you're using `v50.0` of the endpoint? Gave it a crack with the `v50.0` endpoint and its still throwing 404 errors.

Comment: @lu_ke____ I understand that it is a variable. I want to emphasize that 404 happened because the endpoint URL has a special character that is shown as red in the image above. You will need to remove it and try the GET call to succeed. See similar [post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/328293/smartdatadiscovery-predictiondefinitions/328818#328818) from past.

Comment: Of course salesforce would put special characters in their documentation. Thanks for the pick up.

Comment: I’m happy to get the documentation corrected if you can share the link to it. Thank you